# UnboundLocalError ,local variable 'order' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, post, django-models, django-views

i am trying to create an ecommerce website and i want to create an order for the user,however, i got an error saying that the order is referenced before assignment but i cant understand it.

```
def add_to_cart(request, pk):
    
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)  
    order_item,created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        product =product,
        user = request.user,
        ordered = False,
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user,ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order =order[0]
        if order.items.filter(product__id=pk).exists():
            order_item.quantity +=1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request ,"Added additional worker successfully")
            return redirect("ecom:product_desc",id=pk)

        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request ," successfully booked")
            return redirect("ecom:product_desc" ,id=pk)  

    else:
        ordered_date =timezone.now()
        order =Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request," Successfully booked")

        return redirect('product_desc',id=pk)          
    #context ={'desc':desc}
    return render(request ,'products/desc.html',context)  



below is the error message i got.please advise how i can fix this error


model.py file



class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default =1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.product.name}"

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.price

    def get_final_price(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price()   


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True, default =None,blank=True,null=True)
    datetime_ofpayment =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    razorpay_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)

    razorpay_payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)

    razorpay_signature = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if self.order_id is None and self.datetime_ofpayment and self.id:
            self.order_id = self.datetime_ofpayment.strftime('PAY2ME%Y%m%dODR') + str(self.id)

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



    def get_total_price(self):
        total =0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
                total +=order_item.get_final_price()

        return total

    def get_total_count(self):
        order =Order.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        return order.items.count()            
   

urls.py file




    path('add_product/', views.add_products, name='add_product'),
    path('product_desc/<pk>', views.product_desc, name='product_desc'),
    path('add_to_cart/<pk>', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),local variable 'order' referenced before assignment

UnboundLocalError at /ecom/add_to_cart/3
local variable 'order' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://canwork.herokuapp.com/ecom/add_to_cart/3
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'order' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: /app/ecom/views.py, line 50, in add_to_cart
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.13
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 23 Jul 2021 10:18:36 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 179, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/app/ecom/views.py, line 50, in add_to_cart
        order =order[0] …
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear. At the point where Python tries to execute `order =order[0]` in `add_to_cart()`, the list `order` has not been assigned. The code only assigns it lower down.

Comment: @BoarGules what's the solution?

Comment: It is clear that `order=order[0]` makes no sense. You obviously have to put a different variable name to the right of the `=`. But from your code I can't possibly guess what you intended. What is that line supposed to do? I can't answer that, but you should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is because of this line:

```
order =order[0]
```

You haven't defined what `order` is but you are already using it with `order[0]`. But judging from that, you may be trying to get the first of the current user that is has `ordered` as `False`. So you can just do this:

```
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False).first()
    if order:
        if order.items.filter(product__id=pk).exists():
            order_item.quantity +=1
            order_item.save()
            ...
```

Comment: thanks @bdbd .i sorted it out. ur solution is apt too